# Is there a way to share stored data for a conversation with a different Action?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm looking for a way to share data between Actions for an anonymous user. To be able to set up a small amount of data in one action, which I can access in a different action.

The info I'd like to share in particular is the userStorage object mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data.

It wouldn't need to be this object though, if there's another way to do it?

Everywhere seems to focus on it being action specific — is there a way to share it? Or is this completely unsupported?

Answer (score 3):

This is deliberately unsupported for privacy reasons.

If you want data between Actions, the Actions can use Google Sign In to get an ID that both share, and store data in a datastore that both have access to.